# Does my use of the notation $P(\cdot|\Omega)$ make sense?

Tags: probability, terminology

I'm new to probability theory.

Let's say that I have the following situation:

Three identical boxes have different collections of doughnuts in them. The box on the
left ($L$) has 2 plain ($p$) doughnuts, 3 maple ($m$) doughnuts, and 5 chocolate ($c$) doughnuts. The box in the
middle ($M$) has 2 plain doughnuts, 3 maple doughnuts, and 5 chocolate doughnuts. The box on
the right ($R$) has 3 plain doughnuts, 4 maple doughnuts, and 6 chocolate doughnuts. You grab
a box at random and without looking inside you grab a doughnut from that box.

Background: I gave this problem on an Elementary Statistics exam with the question "What is the probability of selecting a plain doughnut?" Since any box and any doughnut inside a box could be selected from the information given in the problem, my answer was $7/33\approx 0.2121$, which is the number of plain doughnuts divided by the total number of doughnuts. One of my students used the rule of total probability: If we let event $A=\{p\}$, event $B=\{L\}$, event $C=\{M\}$, and event $D=\{R\}$, then (I think)
\begin{align*}
P(A)&=P(A|B)P(B)+P(A|C)P(C)+P(A|D)P(D) \\
&=(2/10)(1/3)+(2/10)(1/3)+(3/13)(1/3)\\
&=41/195\approx 0.2103 
\end{align*}

That's assuming that $\{B,C,D\}$ is even a legitimate partition here. [Roussas (*A First Course in Mathematical Statistics*, 1973) defines a *partition* as a set $A_i\in U$ such that $A_i \cap A_j = \emptyset, i\neq j$ and $\sum_i A_i=\Omega$ where $U$ is a $\sigma$-field for some probability space $(\Omega,U,P)$.]

Now that the background has been established, I'm curious to know which one of us is correct and why. The problem is that I don't know enough about probability theory to come to a good answer. I don't want the problem solved for me, but the two questions below will help me in my process.

I have started to answer the question from what I do know. My questions are below.

I'm letting $\Omega_B=\{L,M,R\}$ represent the outcome space for the boxes. We'll keep the events $B,C,D$ as defined above. I'm also letting $\Omega_d=\{p,m,c\}$ be the outcome space for the doughnuts.

I have two questions:

1. I'm trying to represent in notation "the probability that we select a plain doughnut given that we can choose *any* box". I'm going with $P(A|\Omega_B)$ but I'm not sure that using $\Omega_B$ would be the correct way to represent that. I could also try $P(A|B,C,D)$, but I'm not sure that that would make much sense either.
2. I would also like to represent in notation the "probability that we select a plain doughnut given that we select *any* box and *any* doughnut. I'm going with $P(A|\Omega_B\cap \Omega_d)$ here, but, again, I'm not sure how you would represent this here.

If what I am doing is sound, great! If not, how would this situation be approached?

Let me know if there are still ambiguities in my question. Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to CV, James.  This notation doesn't make any sense to me, because I would expect "$\Omega_B$" in this context to refer to an *event,* but I am unable to interpret $\{L,M,R\}$ as an event.  Could you explain what you mean by "what ... theorists typically do"??

Comment: I'm using $\Omega_B$ as an outcome space for the boxes. As for my question, if the notation doesn't make sense (that I can't represent picking any box with $\Omega_B$), what would the correct way to do it be?

Comment: I think the question is understandable and should not be closed -- the OP just proposed his own understanding of the sample space and probability expressions, it could be wrong of course, but the point of his question is to ask for confirmation and advices (though the title could have been edited to such as "Does my usage of the notation $P(\cdot |\Omega)$ make sense?").

Comment: @Zhanxiong Thanks for the advice on the title.

Comment: @Zhanxiong I closed it out of concern there are multiple conflicting interpretations, which threatens to lead to multiple contradictory answers, thereby helping nobody.  What I could not determine, and still cannot, is what the notation is trying to represent, or even whether the question is about the meaning, definition, or notation for conditional probabilities, or perhaps about something else altogether.  I had hoped that getting some clarification of the second question about "theorists" might give some useful clues to resolve the ambiguities.

Comment: @whuber - I'm still not sure where the misinterpretation is coming in. We have 3 boxes. Any one of the boxes could be selected since the problem says that one of them is selected at random. Thus, the outcome space for the boxes, the set of all outcomes for the boxes, is $\Omega_B$ which I have defined above. As to my question about the "theorists", in this context, assuming that my method is incorrect, would would be the correct way to use this notation? Does that clear it up?

Comment: Question should be opened. If the notation make sense, is the whole point of the question, if it doesn't, then that's the answer and not a reason to close it

Comment: So i think what James means is relatively clearly two random variables:  the Box $B$ and the doughnut $D$, which then has a joint distribution on $\Omega = \Omega_B \times  \Omega_D$. From there (1) either means $P(p| B)$ or $P(p|B\in  \Omega_B)$ and (2) should be $P(p |\Omega) = P(p)$. I'm not sure how to edit the question without removing the actual misunderstandings.

Comment: @Lukas Although neither the box nor the doughnut are random variables, I will accept that you and other commenters have a common and correct understanding of the question.

Comment: @LukasLohse I think that your notation $P(p|B\in\Omega_B)$ is a better notation. Check my recent edit for a better description of the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the big edit JHBatley. It makes it much clearer what is going on. As you might have already guessed most people here think your approach is confused.

In my opinion, where your notation goes awry is that you don't properly respect that choice of Box $B$ and choice of doughnut $D$ are non interchangeable and therefore the way to combine them into your space of elementary/atomic (there is no standard term) events $\Omega$ needs to be with $2$-tupels(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tuple), also known as an ordered pairs.
$$\Omega = \Omega_B \times \Omega_D = \{(b, d) : \text{such that } b\in \Omega_B \text{ and }d\in \Omega_D \}$$

Under specific circumstances $n$-tupels form $n$-dimensional vectors so if you want you can think about $B, D$ as the two dimensions of your randomness.

Now Question 1: So $P(D = p|\text{ we can choose any box})$, well you could represtent that with $P(D = p| B \in \Omega_B)$, but as you can see from the definition of $\Omega, B \in \Omega_B$ is true for all its elements therefore this is just  $P(D = p| \Omega) = P(D = p)$, because you didn't condition anything. In short: you always pick a box, there is nothing to think about! If you want the option of not picking a box you need to add an element to $\Omega_B$ that represents that.

Question 2: Really the same as Question 1, you always pick, so conditioning is meaningless here.What you meant by $\Omega_B \cap \Omega_D $ is my definition of $\Omega$. Also you should have noticed that $\Omega_B \cap \Omega_D $ is the empty set $ \emptyset$ and conditioning on $\emptyset$ would involve divinding by $P(\emptyset) = 0$.

The Test-Question: $\{\{B = L\},\{B = C\},\{B = R\}\} $ is a perfectly good partition of $\Omega$ and if you 1st pick box at random then a doughnut from within the box  your student has the correct answer. Just consider the extreme example of $1$ plain in boxes $L, C$ each and $98$ chocolate in $R$. $P(D = p)$ would be $2/3$ not $2/100$

Comment: Hi @LukasLohse, being appreciative of your answer, I would like to say that I disagree that "most" people here think my approach confused. Zhanxiong understood what I was asking and so did rep_ho. Now I admit that my wording could have been clearer for the interpretation, but that's still a long shot from "confused".